# Magento 2 Video's not showing with images on product detail page when enable zoom for product

Tags: magento2, product-detail-page, fotorama

Video Not showing on product detail page when enabling zoom option from amasty color swatches please help for this.

Comment: Any error on console or log file?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya no error in the console or log file